# What is the effect of the trailing comma in this numpy assignment?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow2.0

I am using the code below as a template for writing a data generator function in TensorFlow and I was wondering if the trailing comma below is necessary or useful:

```py
def __data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp):
    'Generates data containing batch_size samples' # X : (n_samples, *dim, n_channels)
    # Initialization
    X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_channels))
    y = np.empty((self.batch_size), dtype=int)

    # Generate data
    for i, ID in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
        # Store sample
        X[i,] = np.load('data/' + ID + '.npy')

        # Store class
        y[i] = self.labels[ID]

    return X, keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=self.n_classes)
```

Does the comma in `X[i,]` do anything? I've searched high and low and run a bunch of tests with similar code in Jupyter and I can't find any difference between using or not using the comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not much difference, except for the fact that adding the comma is just making part of the code redundant. But do note that **the comma can slow down the program**, see below:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('a[:3,]', 'import numpy as np; a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])')
0.26200279999999765
>>> timeit('a[:3,]', 'import numpy as np; a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])')
0.27410390000000007
>>> timeit('a[:3,]', 'import numpy as np; a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])')
0.3642131000000006
>>> timeit('a[:3,]', 'import numpy as np; a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])')
0.3105785999999995
>>> timeit('a[:3,]', 'import numpy as np; a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])')
0.2766163000000006
>>> timeit('a[:3,]', 'import numpy as np; a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])')
0.2650689999999969
>>> timeit('a[:3,]', 'import numpy as np; a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])')
0.2776439999999951
>>> timeit('a[:3,]', 'import numpy as np; a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])')
0.3056855999999968
>>> timeit('a[:3,]', 'import numpy as np; a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])')
0.2718677000000014
>>> timeit('a[:3,]', 'import numpy as np; a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])')
0.2666911999999968
```

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('a[:3]', 'import numpy as np; a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])')
0.25228500000000054
>>> timeit('a[:3]', 'import numpy as np; a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])')
0.23471499999999423
>>> timeit('a[:3]', 'import numpy as np; a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])')
0.3306362000000007
>>> timeit('a[:3]', 'import numpy as np; a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])')
0.2560698000000059
>>> timeit('a[:3]', 'import numpy as np; a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])')
0.2566029000000043
>>> timeit('a[:3]', 'import numpy as np; a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])')
0.24175780000000202
>>> timeit('a[:3]', 'import numpy as np; a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])')
0.23682909999999424
>>> timeit('a[:3]', 'import numpy as np; a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])')
0.2400262999999967
>>> timeit('a[:3]', 'import numpy as np; a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])')
0.2468849999999918
>>> timeit('a[:3]', 'import numpy as np; a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])')
0.22863809999999773
```

---

For for more information *(though I'm sure you already know this)*, adding a comma after an object that's between two brackets does make a difference, as with it, a tuple is created and without it, the brackets get dismissed:

```
a = (1)
print(a)
a = (1,)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
1
(1,)
```

Comment: Redundant in what way?

Comment: The braces in your example are unnecessary. `a = 1,` also achieves the same result.

Comment: @flakes Yep, but not when we want to pass a tuple into the arguments of a function :)

Comment: @DarrellHougen In computer programming, redundant code is code in a program that is unnecessary, such as the comma we're discussing right now :)

Comment: Oh wow. I was totally skeptical about that timing test, so I re-arranged it a bit. That is considerably more costly than I ever thought it would be. Like 5-10% more. https://gist.github.com/cal-pratt/83361d6dce0368b9560a0853ebfa7d63

Comment: @AnnZen Thanks for the timing example. I wasn't sure if a tuple would be created and didn't know the effect on timing.

Comment: But keep in mind those times are **us**  (e.g. 200 ns).  This indexing operation is trivial, so minor changes in calling syntax create small changes in  times.

Comment: @hpaulj Sure, but one would probably have a different opinion on this if they were working on real-time interactive programs with lengthy while loops *(that's me nowadays)*.

Answer (score 1):

Timings for non-trivial assignments:

```
In [146]: x=np.zeros((100,100,100))
In [148]: y=np.arange(10000.).reshape(100,100)
In [149]: x[1]=y

In [150]: timeit x[1]=y
6.89 µs ± 64.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [151]: timeit x[1,]=y
6.89 µs ± 70.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [153]: timeit x[1,:,:]=y
7.12 µs ± 3.44 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

times for a trivial task:

```
In [154]: timeit x[1]
194 ns ± 3.79 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [155]: timeit x[1,]
205 ns ± 10.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Sometimes in my answers I include trailing colons, `x[1,:,:]`.  The code doesn't care, but it can help humans beware that it's accessing one of several dimensions.